# Getting a file via CURL Posting Data

Tags: php, curl

I have a web service which you post data to and it returns you a txt.gz file. I'm trying to use cURL to post up the information, however I'm not sure how to be ready and handle the file which comes back at me to download.

I'm getting a successful response; but the file is 0 KB, and obviously isn't downloading.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is currently what I'm doing:

```
$url = 'http://www.mywonderfulurl.com';
$fields = array('id'=>'123');
$fields_string = 'id=123';
$useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";

$ch = curl_init();

// set user agent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 250);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, 'download.txt.gz');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    if (file_put_contents('download.txt.gz', curl_exec($ch)) === false) {
        // Handle unable to write to file error.
        echo('you failed');
        exit;
    }



echo curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never writing to the file.

You need to write the result to file.

```
fwrite($fp, $result);
```

You are probably better off using `file_put_contents`, then you don't need to open/close the file.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

```
if ($file_put_contents('download.txt.gz', curl_exec($ch)) === false) {
    // Handle unable to write to file error.
}
```

But maybe using the $result in between to check the request was actually ok before saving it to file.

You should check the return from `curl_exec()`

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === false) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

Writing `false` to a file would result in an empty file, so this could be whats happening.

Comment: hmm; i switched a few things out; not getting a fail however it's still leaving me with a 0 kb file.

Comment: expanded answer, check the return of curl_exec doesn't equal false.

Comment: @Jacob: Thank you for your help; sadly by adding that; nothing still shows up as an error; and i'm still getting a 0kb file.  I'm not sure why though.

Comment: Have you tried doing it manually through the browser? create a form that posts the same values and see what it returned?

Comment: Yes.  There are two parts, an initial login, and once I'm logged in I request these params, and it prompts file for me to start downloading.

Comment: how does your login work? curl would beed to be logged in as well.